# Why do I need to call layoutIfNeeded() when adding a layer mask to a subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

My main view has a subview, which I add a mask to using the following extension:

```
extension UIView{
func addTopRoundCorners(){
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.topLeft, UIRectCorner.topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

}

I have notice the effects of this code on my subview only appears on screen if I call `layoutIfNeeded()` on my main view before adding the mask to my subview. I'd really appreciate if someone could explain to me why this is?

Comment: are you using autolayouts?

Comment: How well do you understand the view lifecycle? In lay terms, you are telling the OS to re draw what is needed.

Comment: Yes, I am using auto layout. However, I added them through code not the storyboard. I also know when using auto layout you must call `layoutIfNeeded()` in order for the mask to work, but why? @apineda

Comment: I am somewhat familiar. @dfd

Comment: Then maybe I'm not clear on what you are asking. You add something to a view - a layer, a subview, a slider change, whatever - and the OS needs to be signaled to update things. Some of the changes (most likely a user interaction) automatically trigger this update. But others (adding a sublayer, depending on when you do) do not and therefore require something to trigger the OS to refresh things. It sounds like you know this. But if so, then what are you asking? Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: That's right, when there is a change calling the `layoutIfNeeded()` updates the user interface. However, I am calling the method before I add the layer mask, in other words before the change happens. If I call it after the mask addition the interface would not update. It also depends on if I am using auto layout, which I am, if I wasn't using auto layout I wouldn't have to call `layoutIfNeeded()`. Those are a few things that are confusing me. @dfd

Comment: That is a good question! Sorry if I didn't glean that from your OP. My best guess: Auto layout does it's own thing. As in, it doesn't care about frames - which can be set in *viewDidLoad* for subviews. On the other hand, it *does* need the superview's bounds (and probably frame) before laying out everything. I just know that (a) "pre" auto layout I could set my frames (and struts and springs) and know how things behave. I could also know how things were laid out, regardless of things like screen resolution and size. But (b) "post" auto layout? I wait until the subviews are to be laid out.

Comment: Where did you call this method? The view probably has not been layout yet when you call this method, add a breakpoint and check if `self.bounds` is (0,0,0,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layoutIfNeeded` will calculate position and size of your view. If you call your `addTopRoundCorners()` function before the final position and size is calculated, then `self.bounds` that is used to create `UIBezierPath` will be wrong.

Auto layout will not automatically resize your mask layer, and will not call `addTopRoundCorners` to recreate the path.